# Android browser generates new openid id

Tags: bug, status-norepro, openid, android

1. log in at desktop using yahoo open id
2. log in at android browser using same yahoo open id.

Expected. You get the same id.

What happens. You have to create another account

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this on iPhone -- I logged in as a Yahoo user ([our old pal Eggs McLaren](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147114)) from desktop and from iPhone just fine.

Email us the actual OpenID strings, to the "contact us" address at the bottom of every webpage.

Comment: Ha, just reproduced on my desktop.
I have one tab logged in as my regular profile. And was informed that my account was associated to another.

I checked my other accoun and it was this one! cliked this question. And to my surprise, i'm not logged in in meta.stackoverflow.

i logged in to the very same openID provider and account. and here i'm logged as this random user. on the other tab, i'm still logged to my regular account.

maybe something wrong with Yahoo?